# Remove unnecessary spacing in flalign

Tags: spacing, flalign

I would like to remove the unnecessary spacing between in the last two lines. The equal signs should be aligned but all a little bit more to the right. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&\quad\rightarrow u(x_1,x_2,T) 
&&= \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} + \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right)_+ &\\
%
&\quad\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow -\infty}  u(x_1,x_2,t) 
&&= \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} P(d_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(d_2) &\\
%
&\quad\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow -\infty}  u(x_1,x_2,t) 
&&= \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} P(\hat{d}_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(\hat{d}_2) &\\
%
&\quad\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow \infty}  \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1}\right)
&&= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right) &\\
%
&\quad\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow \infty}  \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2}\right)
&&= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} - 1\right) &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is there spacing in the first place?

Again thanks in advance!

Comment: `flalign`, like `align` is desiged for showing muliple equations on a line so  `a=b    c=d` so adds space between each "pair". use `alignat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flalign`, like `align` is designed for showing muliple equations on a line so  `a=b    c=d`. So it adds space between each "pair". The space shows more with `flalign` as that is "Full Length align" so by design stretches the groups apart as far as possible, to cover the width of the page.

Use `alignat`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{-1}
&\rightarrow u(x_1,x_2,T) 
&&= \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} + \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right)_+ \\
%
&\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow -\infty}  u(x_1,x_2,t) 
&&= \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} P(d_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(d_2)\\
%
&\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow -\infty}  u(x_1,x_2,t) 
&&= \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} P(\hat{d}_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(\hat{d}_2)\\
%
&\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow \infty}  \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1}\right)
&&= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right)\\
%
&\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow \infty}  \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2}\right)
&&= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} - 1\right)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so far! The reason I did not use alignat is because I want the whole thing to be aligned to the left side (the rightarrows) - preferably with some offset. How would I do that?

Comment: `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` and set `\mathindent`  or for a one-off in an otherwise centred document use `$\begin{aligndat}...`  @Alex_qp

Comment: Thank you so much! It works with fleqn.

Comment: @Bernard that's true but did you mean to make that comment on your answer, as I haven't mentioned the `nccmath` `fleqn` environment here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:You're right, but I only focused on the question author's comment, and didn't see it was a comment about your answer. I'll move it within seconds

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath` and `alignat*`:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{fleqn}[1em]
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\rightarrow u(x_1,x_2,T)
    &&= \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} + \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right)_+ \\
    %
    &\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow -\infty} u(x_1,x_2,t)
    &&= \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} P(d_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(d_2) \\
    %
    &\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow -\infty} u(x_1,x_2,t)
    &&= \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} P(\hat{d}_1) - e^{-r(T-t)} P(\hat{d}_2) b\\
    %
    &\rightarrow \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow \infty} \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1}\right)
    &&= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2} - 1\right) \\
    %
    &\rightarrow \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow \infty} \left(u(x_1,x_2,t) - \alpha_2 e^{\sigma_2 x_2}\right)
    & &= e^{-r(T-t)} \left(\alpha_1 e^{\sigma_1 x_1} - 1\right)
    \end{alignat*}
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using \begin{alignat}{2}.... instead of {-1}? What does this parameter do?

Comment: @Alex_qp: because there are two alignment points: the arrows and the = sign.

Comment: Note the optional argument of the fleqn environment is used to set the distance from the left margin at which the equations begin (the default is 0).